# PHP: Read character after position

Tags: php, string

I have:

```
<?php
$word = "hello";
$emaillen = strlen($word);
$lnpos = $emaillen + 1;
?>
```

I want to read the first character after `$lnpos`. The character after `$lnpos` is 1.
The text I am reading from is:

```
hello.1;
```

Thank you for your kind attention!

Comment: Try `echo substr('hello.1', $lnpos)`

Comment: Oh that worked! Thank you for your answer. I was confused before your edit....

Comment: Ya sorry, I was confused on the OP b/c it should have been at '.' but saw you did a +1 to get past it.

Answer (score 1):

you can access characters like arrays so if $lnpos is your position and you want to access the character at $lnpos + 1 just do:

```
$yourstring[$lnpos + 1];
```

Remeber to check that $lnpos + 1 < strlen($yourstring)

Hope this helps